# How to sync between my mongodb and Google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I would like to use Google Spreasheets for allowing people to visualize and edit the data of tables stored in mongodb collections.

The data is created by web services, around 50 mongodb collections are created daily. (The data is tabular in essence: all the documents of a collections are flat key value objects with the same keys.)

Now, I want to allow people inside my company to visualize and edit the data of the tables using Google Spreadsheet.

I am looking for the best way to keep mongobd and Google Spreasheets in Sync.

I looked at Google Sheets API and Google Drive API.
It seems to be feasible. My design is:

1. Each time a web service writes data to a mongo collection, it updates the corresponding spreadsheet via Google Sheets API (java)
2. Once a minute, using Google Drive Revision API, I check what spreadsheets were recently updated.

I could differentiate between changes made by people through the Spreadsheets app and changes made by the web service, because the web service uses a special user.

But as far as I know, the Google Drive revision API doesn't allow to get only the changes that are made by a set of users.

Is my design appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to go with your change tracking method have your data persistence layer push to both MongoDB and to some sort of queue (Redis? RabbitMQ?).  Then have another service read off the queue to push the data into Google Sheets.  That way you have a ordered record of what's suppose to happen without slowing down the persisting of your data (at least not by much).  This can be made pretty robust so that if your service is down, or the Google Sheets API is down, you wont lose track and have to do a full resync.

I'm not sure how much data we're talking about here, but if possible it might be easier to dump the entire DB to a spreadsheet every few minutes, or just as often as you really need, rather than change tracking everything.

You may also want to check out Business Intelligence tools if you have the budget.  They're specifically designed to provide information to business people based on your data.  They may also have a connector for it to suck in all the data from MongoDB, without you having to right an integration layer.  Then you can focus on building things more important to your business.

Comment: What about the other direction: updating mongodb when a change occurs on Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to send data when a change occurred on your collection but you could have an app script that GET data from your mongo collection everytime you open your spreadsheet or every minute or every day.

To do that, you could have that app script

```
function importTimesheetsfromMongo() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("YourSheet");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var sheet_data = range.getValues();

  // getting the data
  var getData = UrlFetchApp.fetch('YourURL').getContentText();

  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(getData)

  var toAdd = []

  // iterate through each object
  for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){ 
    // check if id exist in column
    var isIdInRange = sheet_data.some( function(row){
      return row[0] == jsonObj[i]._id
    });

    if(! isIdInRange){
      var new_row = [jsonObj[i].emp ,jsonObj[i]._id];
      toAdd.push(new_row);
    }
  }

  LockService.getScriptLock().waitLock(60000);
  sheet
  .getRange(
    sheet.getLastRow() + 1,
    1,
    toAdd.length,
    toAdd[0].length
  )
  .setValues(toAdd);

}
```

And then in you create a HTTP endpoint with GET method with a function

```
exports = function(payload){
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  const db = mongodb.db("YourDB");
  const coll = db.collection("YourCollection");
  
  return coll.find({}).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own in-house solution using Google's API and MongoDB change streams. Mongo's change streams make it pretty easy to track events in MongoDB, but the Google API is trickier to work with. For two-way syncs, you also need to figure out a way to map records to each other, since Google Sheets does not offer unique record IDs
Pros: totally tailored to your use case, max flexibility
Cons: diverts engineering resources, can be very high-maintenance, not super scalable

[Zapier](https://zapier.com) could also work for a simple sync (it's more of an automation tool than a data syncing tool). Zapier can be pretty limiting though: you have to set up zaps for every possible data change (e.g. updates, added records, etc), you can quickly hit your monthly zap limit if you do batch updates, the fastest sync is 15 minutes unless you pay for the Professional plan, and it's impossible to do two-way syncing without hitting an infinite loop.
Pros: No-code, familiar to previous Zapier users Cons: Surprisingly high-maintenance, can quickly hit monthly limits, slow syncing, no two-way syncs

There are also many ETL/reverse ETL solutions out there. ETL = "Extract-Transform-Load." Basically, ETL is a way to get data from your SaaS tools (e.g. Salesforce, Zoho, ADP) into your data warehouse. Fivetran, Stitch, and Airbyte are some big players. Reverse ETL: the opposite! Data flows from your warehouse to the SaaS tools. Hightouch, Census, and Grouparoo are big players. These tools are robust, but they can also get a bit complex and pricey for smaller companies and do not support two-way syncing. They are also slow -- 10 minute sync intervals is usually the fastest you can do. For two-way syncs, you also need a way to handle merge conflicts (i.e., what happens if somebody is editing the same record in G Sheets and MongoDB at the same time?)
Pros: Many players in the space to choose from, a lot of integrations, can get expensive
Cons: Slow syncing speeds (usually 10 minutes at the fastest), too complicated for many use cases, no two-way syncs Method #4: Use Bracket for two-way syncs

If you just need data in two different places to match in real time [Bracket](https://www.usebracket.com/?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=signups) and you don't want to deal with the hassle of setting up ETL and reverse ETL. Or maybe you want simple bidirectional syncing that's engineer-friendly, yet simple enough for nontechnical users to set up. Bracket is designed for use cases like this. You can connect G sheets with MongoDB and set up one-way or two-way syncs with a few clicks.

Pros: built for bidirectional syncing but can also handle one-way syncs, simple onboarding Cons: Still building out integrations for new frontend tools, but our G sheets connector is live! I included more links at the actual blog post that might be helpful.